# Evaluate $\iiint_{D}(x^2+y^2)^2\,dx\,dy\,dz$ over cylinder section

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Evaluate $$\iiint_{D}(x^2+y^2)^2\,dx\,dy\,dz\,,$$ where $$D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 1, 0\leq z\leq 1,0\leq y\}$$
I used GeoGebra to represent my domain.
It is that right section of the cylinder, enclosed by the planes $z=0$, $z=1$. As I have a cylinder, is it a good ideea to use polar coordinates or should I use a projection of the domain on xOy? In fact, when I know which to use?
Could you solve this as an example, I don`t have much. Thank you, it would be great.

[image]

Comment: Some kind of polar coordinates would be useful, and the way you can tell is by the integrand and bounds combined, not by one on their own. Can you which polar coordinates you have to use?

Comment: The cylindrical polar coordinates, yes, but could you elaborate an answer such that it`s more clear, for example, I quite don`t see how I could tell this by ,,the integrand and bounds combined". Thanks!

Comment: If the integrand was something like $\tan x$, you could see why cylindrical coordinates would not be ideal ($\int r\tan(r\cos\theta) = $ ??). Or if the bounds were a box like the unit cube.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. What should be used then?

Comment: At that point, just start crying. The tears will blur the problem into something more doable. That's my advice anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular example, it seems optimal to use polar coordinates, since you can represent $x^2+y^2$ in a very simple and covinient way. Let $(x,y,z)$ be a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$. You first set $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle of the vector and the "positive" part $x$-axis and $r$ is the length of the vector (in genereal $r>0$ and $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$). You basically use polar coordinates for the plane and leave the third coordinate untouched. With this setting and the given $D$,
$x^2 + y^2=r^2$, and thus $0\leq r\leq 1$ and since $y\geq 0$, $\theta \in [0, \pi]$. Also the Jacobian of this transformation, which we need in order to change variables in the integral, is $r$.

Alos we can use Fubini since it is a continuous function on a compact set and thus it's integrable.

\begin{align}
&\iiint_{D}(x^2+y^2)^2dxdydz 
=
\int_0^1 \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^1 r^4 \cdot r \text{ d}z \text{ d}\theta \text{ d}r 
=
\int_0^1 \int_0^{\pi}r^5 \text{ d}\theta \text{ d}r 
\\&=
\int_0^1 \int_0^{\pi} r^5 \text{ d}\theta \text{ d}r 
= 
\pi \int_0^1 r^5 \text{ d}r 
=
\dots
\end{align}